# How to make a Squid Proxy server?

Tags: server, proxy, squid

I want to set up squid proxy server for monitoring user activity in a network and Internet Web URL filtering for user. I also want to configure the user login, user log, user access group, and block unwanted web sites in my network.

Please help me and guide me the full process to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Setting up Squid is fairly simple, install the package with

`sudo apt-get install squid3`

After install, run `man squid3` for details about tailoring Squid to your needs.